# How do I check Approvals != null in formula field on Quote object in salesforce

Tags: formula, quote, approval-process

How do I check, in formula field on Quote object, Approvals != null. I can see in related list that there are 2 Approvals.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be done with a formula alone, since formulas have no way to access child records.

Some other component (process builder, trigger, workflow rule with a cross-object field update, rollup summary field) would be required to get the data onto your parent record (Quote, in this case).

Comment: Hi @derek thanks for the explanation.